# gitlab ci pull_policy for local-only docker images

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

We use gitlab-ci with docker images to test student code. This works fine with images published to docker-hub. We now want to test using images that are only available on the server.

The updated `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml` file with the settings shown below does not seem to be picked up, however, and we keep getting the error message shown below.

Any suggestions?

```
concurrent = 10
check_interval = 0
pull_policy = ["always", "if-not-present"]
```

```
ERROR: Job failed: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for vnijs/rsm-mgta453,
repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': 
denied: requested access to the resource is denied (executor_docker.go:188:1s)
```

Answer (score 0):

u should put `pull_policy = ["always", "if-not-present"]` under  `[[runners.docker]]`

like this：

```
[[runners]]
  name = "xxx"
  url = "xxx"
  token = "x"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    image = "pnpm-v6"
    pull_policy = ["always", "if-not-present"]
```

Comment: Thanks. Does this mean we need to specify `name`, `url`, etc. for any/all runners or can we get this to apply to any runner that is active and leave the other arguments out?